# Separating admin's functionality to admin's dashboard or integrating it to the regular users' appearance

Tags: website-design, administration

Could you please help me to choose between the options below?

- splitting admin's view of the web application to a regular user's dashboard and admin's dashboard
- having the single appearance for both admins and users but with some functionality visible for admins only

The workflows of admins and regular users are very different in our application, and I cannot decide whether admins should have the so called "User dashboard" with the relatively small number of activities available both for users and admins, and the "Admin dashboard" with the administrative only functionality. OR whether we should integrate admin's functionality into the regular user's appearance?

Comment: Considering that Adobe admin console and cloud, is there a reason they separate those two views?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **Single Appearance** is the way to  go.

Keeping the Admin section visible to Users might confuse them.

Having Single Appearance means that Admins will feel privileged to have these Powerful features to them, and a User who turns into an Admin will still know the Interface pretty well, just with some more features.

Cleanliness will be a plus.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends upon development time and product scope. If your (development) resources are limited and you are short of time for release choose the completely separate admin/user dashboard approach. You will benefit with specific and fast implementation let alone future simple modifications for admin purposes.

One the other hand if you want a well-engineered approach you must choose the single appearance option.

In my opinion, most of the times I would have gone with second option.

Answer (score 0):

The only input I can offer is from a programming perspective: do not repeat yourself.

Is there any value in having two separate views for this data? I know several popular sites (WordPress, etc.) just add additional functionality based on your role/permissions.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is that there are blocks of data that regular users can read only but admins are supposed to spend most of their time by managing such blocks. So having separate views look logical (at least for me). On the other hand both admins and users will use other blocks of functionality, and I'm not sure switching between 'admin dashboard' to 'user dashboard' would be very convenient for admins.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated dashboard (which users and admins are on same place) is literally hard to be well-implemented.

Without designing the right way, how to split user input, and what to be common on API, your system could become a mess. Most of the time when I see those dashboards, below the UI are spaghetti codes.

I will choose separate dashboard design approach, with inner common API and separate business layer instead.

Comment: I don't understand how your recommendation relates to the user's experience? This is more about the quality of the code, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I'm getting messed up with the other answer that about code quality.